# Law of total probability applied to conditional probability

Tags: conditional-probability

Sorry for the really simple question. 
I am reading a book about psychophysiology and I got lost at one point. I will take out all the unrelevant information and just go straight to the point. The book present this probabilities:

1) f(r,t|E)=Pr(**r**=r, **T**=t| E); where E, from now on, is defined as a vector of variables.

2) g(x|E)=Pr(**X**=x|E);

3) h(r,t|x)=Pr(**r**=r, **T**=t| x);

and finally it shows that
"by the law of total probability applied to the conditional probability"

4)   $$f(r,t|E)=\int  g(x|E)*h(r,t|x) dx.$$

**How can I derive 4 from 1-2-3?**

In the text it is said that (**r,t**) has no direct connection with E exepct as it is mediated by the parameter **X**. I suspect that this means that (**r,t**) and E are independent, but (**r,t**) and X are not. I also guess that **X** and **E** dependent. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not saying $(R,T)$ and $E$ are independent, but that they are conditionally independent given $X=x$.  So it is saying $\Pr(R=r, T=t|X=x,E=e)=\Pr(R=r, T=t|X=x)$.

You are then integrating over all $x$ to remove the [nuisance parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuisance_parameter).

You have the conditional probability statement $\Pr(A=a,B=b)=\Pr(A=a|B=b)\Pr(B=b)$ which you can extend to $\Pr(A=a,B=b|C=c)=\Pr(A=a|B=b,C=c)\Pr(B=b|C=c)$.  Then summing over $b$ you get $$\Pr(A=a|C=c) = \sum_b \Pr(A=a,B=b|C=c)$$ $$=\sum_b \Pr(A=a|B=b,C=c)\Pr(B=b|C=c).$$

Now you need to replace $A=a$ by $R=r, T=t$; replace $B=b$ by $X=x$; and replace $C=c$ by $E=e$.  Then use the conditional independence statement above.  Finally move from a sum of conditional probabilities to an integral of conditional probability densities with functions $f,g,h$.